# "error in your SQL syntax check the manual corresponds" message in one page

Tags: mysql, sql, database-connection

I'm getting the error message showed in the next paragraph. The code pasted below was working before but now it's giving an error and even the same file is working for other pages and etc...
Please help me out...

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1:

```
<?php 

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db('test') or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Adds to the click count for a particular link
 mysql_query("UPDATE items SET downloads = downloads + 1 WHERE id = $item_id")or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Retrieves information
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = $item_id") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $info = mysql_fetch_array($data); 

header( "Location:" .$info['path'] );

?>
```

Comment: Which query throws the error?  What are `$book_id` and `$item_id` and how are you populating them?

Comment: Put the query in a variable and then echo it, to see if it looks correct.

Comment: sorry @ David its the same $item_id  not book_id i changed it... $item_id it will take from the url

Answer (score 0):

well i solved it myself. only a little changed and i got it working. what i have changed is

> WHERE id = ".$item_id."

```
<?php 

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db('test') or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Adds to the click count for a particular link
 mysql_query("UPDATE items SET downloads = downloads + 1 WHERE id = ".$item_id."")or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Retrieves information
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = ".$item_id."") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $info = mysql_fetch_array($data); 

header( "Location:" .$info['path'] );

?>
```